# Runtime Logging

Tags: android

Does anyone have an idea of how to capture logs continuously and update a list? As I understand

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
```

will read the entire contents of the log buffer and return. But is there a way to continuously read log buffer and update a list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the only way to do it. Don't do this in the production app... it'll drain your battery life quickly.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat logcat -b events");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    // do something with the line

    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: This is a known approach for collecting the logs for the buffer size. I want it to continuously run and keep displaying the update on the screen.